# Calculate bitmask from a given index in a 16 bit architecture

Tags: c, bitmask, 16-bit

I have a function that accepts an index variable of type unsigned long (this type cannot be changed).

```
void func(unsigned long index);
```

I need to convert it to a bitmask such that for index 0 the bitmask will be 1, for index 1 bitmask will be 2, for 2 it will be 4 and so on.

I have done the following:

```
mask = 1 << index;
```

The problem is that I'm working with an architecture of 16 bit , therefore unsigned long variables are shown as 32 bit which messes up this variable. 
(the lowest 16 bits give me the correct value for mask but the highest 16 bits add extra information which messes this up).

i.e. Instead of getting: mask = 0000000000000001 (16 bit)

I'm getting: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0000000000000001 (32 bits)

Is there another way to calculate this bitmask?

Would appreciate help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic code is correct, although I notice you didn't specify the type of `mask`.

If the caller passes a value greater than 15 into `index`, what are you going to do? It sounds like you have to make the most of a bad situation. Depending on the context you could simply return from `func`, you could assert, or you could proceed with a `mask` of zero.

This brings us back to the question of the type of `mask`. I would define it as `unsigned short`, `uint16` or similar, depending on your environment. But other than that, your first attempt was basically correct. It's just a question of error handling.

```
uint16 shift = index & 15;
uint16 mask = 1 << shift;
```

Comment: `1` is signed.  "working with an architecture of 16 bit " --> better to use `uint16 mask = 1u << shift;` (add u).

Answer (score 4):

You have the correct approach. However, the problem with your implementation is that the type of `1` in `1 << index` expression is `int`, with implementation-defined representation. Since you are looking for an `unsigned long` result, use `((unsigned long)1)` instead:

```
unsigned long mask = ((unsigned long)1) << index;
```

If your platform supports [`stdint.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) and you need a mask of some specific width, use `uint32_t` instead:

```
uint32_t mask = UINT32_C(1) << index;
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use an unsigned long literal instead of type-casting it?  `1UL << index`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons That would work too. I like the `UINT32_C` solution better, though.

Comment: Curious code is `((unsigned long)1)` and not `1UL`.